# htaccess is not working after adding query string

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

My URL is:

```
http://example.com/test  (base url)
```

I want to move this into:

```
https://example.com/tset
```

and  if the URL is:

```
http://example.com/test/login?redirect=
```

I change it to:

```
https://example.com/test/login?redirect=
```

and if my URL is:

```
http://example.com/test/login
```

I want to move it to:

```
https://example.com/test/login
```

Comment: Can you show your attempted rule?

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bt.example.com/test/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule https://bt.systweak.com/test/$1 [R,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule as **very first rule** in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bt\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Query string is automatically carried forward to `https://....` URL.

Comment: actually in cant use this rule because i 've pointed an another site to same folder if i will apply this then it will work on both site. thats why i need site specific conftion and rule